# SpringMVC: What is the best strategy to display an Image?

Tags: image, spring-mvc

May I know what is the best strategy to display an image (blob) from database.

using Spring MVC.

Should I load all the image at once from db or create a controller method to get the images individually?

Some tutorial link will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the file on the server rather than the DB, serve up the link address to the file through the controller.

The images should be in a cdn location or similar and the Spring controller just returns a url to them.

EDIT :

If you really must serve up the image from the DB and serve it as bytes, you can find the answer you want [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604509/spring-mvc-image-controller-to-display-image-bytes-in-jsp)

Comment: there is a requirement to save the image in db, but yes I could use some form of catching mechanism

Comment: but is it the most recommended way?

Comment: This seems by far the most recommended solution than any other if you're forced to store the file in the database.  The only other way would be to copy the file from the db onto the file server at runtime and send the link from the controller, but that's a horrific solution.  Serving the byte[] from the controller is the best you're going to get if the file is in the database.